# how to get tags matching with posts id and display records

Tags: mysql, pdo

guys i have the following tables

1. posts
2. tags
3. post_tags

i save postID and tagsID from posts, tags tables in post_tags table as post_id, tag_id

now i wish to display posts matching the tags in my post.php page but how do i do the query to get matching tags?

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE postID LIKE "%'.$id.'%"');                
                $stmt->execute();
                while($rw = $stmt->fetch()){

}
```

here i am sharing my actual data structure and how the data are saved into each tables, hope this could give you an idea to help me with the JOIN table?

these are the 3 tables

```
--
-- Table structure for table `blog_posts`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_posts` (
  `postID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `posterID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `postTitle` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postImg` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postYoutube` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postSlug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postDesc` text,
  `postCont` text,
  `postViews` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `postDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`postID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `blog_posts`
--

INSERT INTO `blog_posts` (`postID`, `posterID`, `catID`, `postTitle`, `postImg`, `postYoutube`, `postSlug`, `postDesc`, `postCont`, `postViews`, `postDate`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, ' Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.', ' Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.jpg', '', '1/lorem-ipsum-giving', '<p> Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>', '<p> Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>', 1, '2017-08-10 11:46:36'),
(2, 1, 3, ' Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.', ' Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.jpg', '', '2/lorem-ipsum-giving', '<p>Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>', '<p>Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>', 0, '2017-08-10 13:38:57'),
(3, 1, 2, 'Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.', 'Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.jpg', '', '3/moong-dal-halwa', '<p>Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>', '<p>Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.</p>', 0, '2017-08-10 13:39:40'));

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `blog_posts_tags`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_posts_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `blog_posts_tags` (`post_id`,`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `blog_posts_tags`
--

INSERT INTO `blog_posts_tags` (`id`, `post_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2),
(7, 1, 4),
(9, 1, 3),
(2, 1, 3),
(10, 1, 2),
(8, 1, 5),
(4, 1, 5),
(24, 2, 2),
(25, 3, 5),
(26, 3, 1));

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `blog_tags`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_tags` (
  `tagID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tagName` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `tagUrl` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tagID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=61 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `blog_tags`
--

INSERT INTO `blog_tags` (`tagID`, `tagName`, `tagUrl`) VALUES
(1, 'American Food', 'american-food'),
(2, 'Bakeries', 'bakeries'),
(3, 'Bars', 'bars'),
(4, 'Beef', 'beef'),
(5, 'Cafe', 'cafe');
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM blog_posts bp JOIN blog_posts_tags bpt ON bp.postID = bpt.post_id
JOIN blog_tags bt ON bt.tagID = bpt.tag_id
WHERE bt.tagName = 'Bakeries';
```

If you want to search by `id`, you can use `t.id` in `WHERE` condition, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM blog_posts bp JOIN blog_posts_tags bpt ON bp.postID = bpt.post_id
JOIN blog_tags bt ON bt.tagID = bpt.tag_id
WHERE bt.tagID = 2;
```

Here, `id` corresponds to id of the post and tag (in respective tables) and `post_id` and `tag_id` are names of corresponding foreign key columns in `post_tags` table.

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c84bcd5/5/0)**.

Comment: im new to this JOIN please bare with my questions :) say i have a variable  id as 20 now how do i display all records from posts table that has its tags stored in posts_tags with tag_id as 20?

Comment: In that case, you can just chage the `WHERE` condition to `WHERE t.id = 20;`

Comment: i tried like this but no records shows $stm = $db->query('SELECT * FROM blog_posts p JOIN blog_post_tags pt ON p.id = pt.post_id JOIN blog_tags t ON t.tagID = pt.tag_id WHERE t.tagID = "'.id.'"');

Comment: Try that query in MySQL admin and see if it returns any result? Maybe there is no record or you are passing `post id` and not `tag id`?

Comment: i have 3 records in table post_tags tag_id with same tagID 20 of tags table

Comment: Can you add the example data in the question?

Comment: i posted my actual database please check once

Comment: @JohnBukung attached the SQL Fiddle. The reason why it didn't return any record is because there was no entry with id `20` in `blog_tags` table.

Comment: yay it work now :) thanks alot i got one last question i need to fetch 3 similar blog_posts with same tags how will that query be like?

Comment: Same query will return all 3 rows with that tag id